# Getting the wrong color value from color picker

Tags: java, android, colors, calendar, color-picker

I am trying to add colorfull dots to my custom Calendarview.
The color can be selected with a colorpicker but the it returns a negative color value like this for example: "-126706"(Red).

The Calendarview needs an int but crashes if i use the color from the colorpicker.It works if i use "R.color.holo_red_dark" but then i cant use different colors. It also works if i take the Constant value of holo_red_dark("17170455").

Is it possible to convert a negative int color to the format like Constant Value of holo_red_dark?

```
dot_color = colorPicker_value; 

    calendarView.setEventDataProvider(new FlexibleCalendarView.EventDataProvider() {
        @Override
        public List<? extends Event> getEventsForTheDay(int year, int month, int day) {

            if (year == year_i && month == month_i_2 && day == today_i) {
                List<CustomEvent> colorLst1 = new ArrayList<>();
                if (dot_color != 0) {


                    colorLst1.add(new CustomEvent(dot_color));
                }
                return colorLst1;
            }
            return null;
        }
    });

    return rootView;
}
```

Comment: Please post the stacktrace of your crash

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because the colorpicker returns an hex representation of the color (in AARRGGBB format), while the method you called expects an `int` representing the ID of a resource. You should create a `Color` instance from the value returned by the colorpicker and then pass this object to the color setter.

For instance the blue color is -16776961 (i.e. 0xff0000ff).

### EDIT:

After investigating the source code of the [FlexibleCalendar](https://github.com/p-v/FlexibleCalendar/) library, I came to this method (from class `com.p_v.flexiblecalendar.view.CircularEventCellView`):

```
@Override
public void setEvents(List<? extends Event> colorList){
    if(colorList!=null){
        paintList = new ArrayList<>(colorList.size());
        for(Event e: colorList){
            Paint eventPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
            eventPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
            eventPaint.setColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(e.getColor()));
            paintList.add(eventPaint);
        }
        invalidate();
        requestLayout();
    }
}
```

As you can see the `int` value is interpreted as a resource identifier (i.e. it tries to get the color from the `res` folder), instead of as an ARGB value.
To fix this you need to subclass `CircularEventCellView` in order to override the `setEvents` method with something similar to this:

```
@Override
public void setEvents(List<? extends Event> colorList){
    if(colorList!=null){
        paintList = new ArrayList<>(colorList.size());
        for(Event e: colorList){
            Paint eventPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
            eventPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
            eventPaint.setColor(e.getColor()); // ONLY THIS LINE CHANGED
            paintList.add(eventPaint);
        }
        invalidate();
        requestLayout();
    }
}
```

After this modifications, if you still want to use resource identifiers, you should manually retrieve their ARGB value through this code:

```
int desiredColor = getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.mycolor);
```

and then set it to the event.

Comment: Thank you but I am not sure if i'm getting this right.Could you give a short example ? :)

Comment: Which library do you use for the color picker widget?

Comment: I inspected the color picker and the calendar library, and both should work with ARGB colors, so I don't think that the problem is in the value returned by the color picker. Where do you get the exception?

Comment: It appears when the calendar should add the new event with the negative int color value from the colorpicker.It trows a NumberFormatException.

Comment: Are you using the class `ExampleCellView2` (or a similar one)? I ask you this question because its implementation perform this code: `eventPaint.setColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(e.getColor()));`, which means that it expects the color to be a resource (e.g. something like `R.color.whatever`). If this is the case you should subclass it and override the `setEvents` method to use ARGB colors

Comment: Hm no i'm using the BaseCellView.Isn't it the same at this point ?

Comment: Well the `BaseCellView` is abstract, you are actually using one of its subclasses. For instance the `CircularEventCellView` suffers from the same "bug" mentioned above

Comment: So what should i do ?